# Simple proof for a continuous-time linear system and impulse $\delta$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, signal-processing, dirac-delta

From Schaum's Outlines of Signals & Systems:

Let's work with continuous-time signals.

Let $T$ be a linear time-invariant system (LTI).

Input $x(t)$ can be expressed as $x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau) \delta(t-\tau) d \tau$.

**Then output $y(t)$ can be expressed as $y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\tau) T\{\delta(t - \tau)\}d\tau$**

I'm not sure how they arrived at the last bolded statement without showing how.  My first thought is to break down the integral into a sum, but not sure if you can do that when working with $\delta$, and it seems like a non-elegant approach.  Please lucidate on a better approach.  Thanks.

Comment: Found this: http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/Convolution.pdf

Comment: Apparently the only way is to break up into piecewise impulses as usual.  So this question is answered for me.